# Split Access database not allowing multiple users

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a split database design in Microsoft Access. Copies of the front end (w/ forms, queries, linked tables) are distributed to multiple users, while the backend (tables only) resides on the network.

Everything works fine when there is only one user, but as soon as a second user tries to open their copy of the front end, they get an error message saying the backend is already in use.
[image]

I've already confirmed that everyone has read & write permissions for the backend.

I've used split databases before and never run into this issue. The only difference is this time I didn't use the Database Splitter utility. I just started with the backend, then created a new database and set up some linked tables. Could that be my problem? Is there a step or setting I'm missing?

Comment: Make sure you're out of the backend db - not editing any tables or code

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm already out of the backend when the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In general, this should work.

However, not only do users need read/write, but they ALSO require create file, and delete file rights to that folder.

The reason is that of couse this is  pure file based system, so on first open, Access will create a ldb (locking file). This locking file is used to manage (allow) multi-user operations of the file.

If the locking file can't be created (first user to open), then multi-user operations can't be used, and in fact in most cases you get a read-only file.

So, users need quite much full rights. I seen some work with delete rights, but that means the last user out does not allow access to remove (delete) that ldb locking file, and it should be allowed for deletion.

so, create file, delete file rights are also required in most cases for this to work.

It also possbile I suppose that one user launched Access, choose open, and browsed to that file, and opened it exclusive. However, you have a split system, and that should not be possible, but it certainly still possible that someone on the network opened the back end file (that shared file) directly with Access, and used the open exclusive option - which would prevent all other users from opening the file.

As noted, since this looks to be a split system, then I would suggest that users don't have the all important create file rights, and delete file rights to that folder. Without such rights, then as noted, multi-user operations can't occur - you get a read only file in most cases.

So, either users don't have enough rights to that folder, or someone has opened the file with Access, and opened the file "exclusive".

Comment: It's good advice, but unfortunately I don't think these are the problem. Everyone already has those rights, which is why it was able to work with previous databases. Also, I know no one is opening the file exclusively because I tested it with a coworker after hours when every one else had the file closed.

Comment: is there and laccdb file in the folder. If you can't delete it then someone or something is in it.

Comment: the detail that this was working and it stopped working? That is significant. There was a recent bug, and perhaps that is or was your issue: https://www.devhut.net/another-access-bug-cannot-open-any-more-databases/